# Modal not opening on first click

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, conflict

My modal that will not open until the button is clicked twice.

If you click the **Savvy Agent Login Button**. The first time the full-page-modal window will not open. On the second click it does.

[enter link description here](http://www.timperis.com/savvy-agent-academy.html)

Comment: please provide some code that you have written for it

Comment: you should fix some errors in your console (screenshot: http://i.dv.tl/aw2j3.jpg)